# Entity Framework, проблема с выборкой из БД

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net

Здравствуйте.
Возникла проблема при использовании Entity Framework Code First: все замечательно завелось, все нормально пишется в БД. Проблема проявляется при выборке некоторых объектов.

Короче: есть классы A и B, которые связываются классом C (связь многие ко многим; т.е. в классе C есть два поля класса A и одно класса B). Первичные ключи у каждого класса - Guid'ы.

Когда мне нужно выбрать экземпляры класса A, связанные с некоторым экземпляром класса B и я обращаюсь к таблице C и формирую завязки, через которые буду тащить экземпляры класса A, из БД вытаскивается вся информация кроме ссылок на экземпляры класса A.

Comment: покажите код

Comment: Я уже сам решил эту проблему, правда немного криво, но работает.

А по поводу кода, то утренний уже затерся :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from A, B, C
where A.id = 17 
and C.A_id = A.id
and B.id = C.B_id;
```

Пишу по-старинке без JOIN.

Comment: не самый оптимальный способ